# Openpyxl causing encode error when using iterators

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have written a script to parse excel documents. I transferred the script to another machine and I am now getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "excelReader.py", line 50, in <module>
wb = load_workbook(doc, use_iterators = True)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 118, in load_workbook
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 69, in repair_central_directory
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 169: invalid start byte
```

This works fine on the machine it was written on and when I remove `use_iterators = True` the script works fine.

Edit: I managed to temporarily fix this by moving the file from the Desktop into Documents

Comment: would you add info about the two machines and python versions?

Comment: The machine it works on is 2.7.2. The other machine is 2.7.1

Comment: The 2.7.2 is mountain lion the 2.7.1 is lion. I tried running it as the root user and not the local user and it worked without error.

Comment: I moved the file of the Desktop and into Documents and this fixed the error

Comment: edit the question explaining how you solved the problem

Comment: I wouldnt consider it a solve, just a temp fix but ok.

Comment: How did you move the file? Did you open the file in Excel and then resave it in a new location?